# What to do about a radiator behind a curtain?

Tags: heating

I have lived in several houses, including my current one, where there is a large radiator behind a curtain, and a window above the radiator.

My question is - just how bad is this for heat efficiency?  Are there any good methods to improve the situation (apart from keeping the curtains open.)

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question, but would you have a picture of the situation you could add to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is terrible, shorten the curtains.   This is like putting a towel over traditional vents.   You are paying to warm up the curtains and probably getting a small fraction of the actual heat the radiator should be dispersing.   But you will have warm curtains!